# Robust relative paths in doctests

Tags: python, unit-testing, doctest

I have a function that takes a path to a file as an argument.

```
output = process('path/to/file.txt')
```

I was wondering if I could easily doctest such a function. I supply an example input file somewhere along the source code, and I can compare the output to what I expect (a string, a python object, or possibly the content of another file).

The issue is that the path in my test is necessarily relative. Relative to the *working directory of the calling script* that is.

This means that all the paths in the docstring must be aware of the test suite's entry point. Clearly that is not ideal. In a more sophisticated testing environment I would be able to use `__file__` to make the path absolute, but in a doctest, `__file__` does not exist.

What is the usual set-up when supplying stimuli as a file?

I hope to hear some better solutions than just 'always run the test suite from the same working directory'.

**EDIT**: I'd like to run the doctests from a centralized test suite entry point.

```
import doctest
import mymodule

doctest.testmod(mymodule)
```

Comment: What is the code that set up the doctests that are referenced here? What I mean is, are they from docstrings inside a module, or a collection of text files?

Comment: Added some info. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are doing this at the module level, I assume that you have also [packaged your modules as a proper Python package](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/) using something like `setuptools` and be deployed onto some environment where the tests will then be executed.  Also, you are only partially correct in the assumption where `__file__` doesn't exist - it also is not defined for a module imported from a zipped Python egg (which are getting more rare as wheels became the de facto packaging method, but they can and do exist).

There are a number of possible approaches, varying in complexity and trade offs and whether it works depend on how the module(s) to be tested are structured.

1) (Not recommended, but included anyway because sometimes this works best in the cases of simplest examples.) The laziest, but the most stable, self-contained and cross platform way - and it assumes that the file opening methods is only done in that one module that was to be tested and are done using the same call (e.g. `open`), the usage of [`extraglobs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#doctest.testmod) argument can be used to substitute the `open` call.  e.g.

```
from io import StringIO
import doctest
import mymodule

files = {
    'path/to/file1.txt': '... contents of file1.txt ...', 
    'path/to/file2.txt': '... contents of file2.txt ...',
} 

def lazyopen(p, flag='r'):
    result = StringIO(files[p] if flag == 'r' else '')
    result.name = p 
    return result

doctest.testmod(mymodule, extraglobs={'open': lazyopen})
```

2) Create a real testsuite, rather than using the builtin ones through `doctest.testmod`

While the shorthand is useful, it is too limited as it is standalone, it cannot be used in conjunction with other testsuites that might get built.  Consider creating a dedicated test module (e.g. `mymodule/tests.py`).  I generally prefer creating a directory named `mymodule/tests`, with unittests named something like `test_mysubmodule.py`, and a `__init__.py` that contain the test_suite setup like so

```
def make_suite():
    import mymodule
    import os

    def setUp(suite):
        suite.olddir = os.getcwd()  # save the current working directory
        os.chdir(targetdir)  # need to define targetdir

    def tearDown(suite):
        os.chdir(suite.olddir)  # restore the original working directory

    return doctest.DocTestSuite(mymodule, setUp=setUp, tearDown=tearDown)
```

So we have covered the basic, but `targetdir` needs to be defined.  Again, multiple things you can consider:

1) Create a temporary directory and populate the directory with the required files using `setup`, and `os.chdir` to that, and remove the temporary directory in `tearDown`.  Either manually write data stored as strings inside the test module, copy from your project or extract from an archive, but how do we actually get those?  Which leads to...

2) If the source files are inside your project, and `setuptools` is available/installed in the environment, simply use [`pkg_resources.resource_filename`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#resource-extraction) to get the location, and assign `targetdir` to that.  The `setUp` might now look something like

```
    def setUp(suite):
        suite.olddir = os.getcwd()
        targetdir = pkg_resources.resource_filename('mymodule', '')
        os.chdir(targetdir)
```

Also, finally, as this is now a real test suite that is produced by the `make_suite` function within `mymodules.tests`, the execution of that must be done using a testrunner, which fortunately is included as part of the default unittest framework as a simple command which can be done like so:

```
$ python -m unittest mymodule.tests.make_suite
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.014s

OK
```

Also, as that is a real test suite, it can be integrated with the testsuite globbing from the `unittest` module to combine everything into a single complete test suite for your entire package.

```
def make_suite():
    # ... the other setup code

    # this loads all unittests in mymodule from `test_*.py` files
    # inside `mymodule.tests`
    test_suite = test_loader.discover(
        'mymodule.tests', pattern='test_*.py')
    test_suite.addTest(
        doctest.DocTestSuite(mymodule, setUp=setUp, tearDown=tearDown))
    return test_suite
```

Again, the `python -m unittest` command may be used to execute the tests returned by the complete test suite.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I very much appreciate the effort you put into this answer. It seems like `pkg_resources.resource_filename` is what I was looking for. I will play around with it tomorrow. If no other answer appears by then I will accept this one. For now, have a +1.

Comment: Thanks again, your answer was both very instructive and on point. For what it's worth, I now settled with a py.test fixture (which is what I am using rather than unittest) that is automatically applied to all doctests. It changes the cwd as you suggested. Works well AFAICT.

Comment: Yeah, `py.test` is fine, it simplifies a lot of the test harness setup workflow, (a very) slight downside is that others that want to test your code will need to have py.test installed in their environment.